# How can we customize the sender name in Docusign emails?

Tags: docusignapi

How can we change the sender name shown in all DocuSign emails before "via DocuSign"? Currently it's using the name from the account but we would like to use company's name instead. Didn't find it anywhere in the email resource file.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This name can be changed by going to the DocuSign web app clicking the top-rhgt menu and selecting "Manage Profile", [image]

Then you can update both your name and the company name (as well as the email address if you need to)

Note that this is account-wide/user-wide for all envelopes. You cannot have this changed per-envelope.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set up [Custody Transfer Rules](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&bundleId=pik1583277475390&topicId=zuo1583277376422.html&_LANG=enus) to achieve this.

1. First set up a DocuSign User with the company's name and email address.
2. Then set up a Custody Transfer Rule from the "Everyone" group (or set up specific groups of users).
3. Select the company DocuSign User from step 1 for the "To" user
4. Transfer Time should be "On Send", and select "Transfer prior to first send"